# scripts not formatted correctly in jade (expressjs)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using expressjs v3.0+ and jade.  I have tried copying the following in my layout.jade file but when I open the HTML page, the scripts are not being used properly (the closing script tag is not in its proper place causing the second script from being imported).  Any suggestions to troubleshoot this will be appreciated - I am trying to confirm if there are any characters between the two script lines in the jade file throwing off the logic.

**layout.jade**

```
   script(src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js')
   script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js')
```

**HTML rendered:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script></script>
```

Comment: just figured - the script wags were one space behind the line indented above - causing the issue.  I added the extra space before the script lines and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pilot error - the script line was one space behind the line indented above - causing the issue. I added the extra space before the script lines and now it works.

**Previously:**

```
    block content

   script(src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')
   script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js
```

**Now (works)**

```
block content

script(src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')
script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js
```